# Wiring Lightswitch Wires to Always On

Tags: wiring, switch

We have an older house and for some reason one of the light switches in the house cut all power to our living room and garage. We have had this switch taped off to prevent this from happening but now I would rather have a more permanent solution.

There are 2 black wires and 1 red wire for this switch. I had the understanding that if I wired all 3 wires together and capped them, it would work, but that is not the case and I am not an electrician.

Does anyone know how I could go about solving this?

[image: 3 wires on the left]

The 3 wires on the left are the problem wires.

Comment: Add a picture of switch and wires to your question, also a general location so we know how to answer properly.

Comment: @crip659 I have already removed the switch so the wires are loose atm. The wires are located in the hallway next to the livingroom for which they cut power to. There are also 2 other switches within this box that all power different lights in the house.

Comment: General location = this is a worldwide site. Wiring standards are different in different parts of the world. Looks like probably USA/Canada, but knowing is better than guessing. If you disconnected all the wires without paying attention to what was connected where, you've made the job harder...

Comment: The 2 black wires were on the right side of the switch and the red wire was at the top of the left. Located in Pennsylvania.

Comment: Off hand sounds like a three way switch circuit.  Do you know if there is another switch somewhere that also controls these lights/circuit?

Comment: There is 1 other switch that controls the the dining room and garage but doesn't control the outlets. The only similarities between these 2 switches is that they both control the garage. I know on both switches, both black wires are controlled by different breaker switches.

Comment: Is that wire big enough to run all the things likely to be used in a garage?

Comment: If you can afford it, call a qualified electrician! Given your unfamiliarity with the theory and practice of home electrical systems evidenced by your description of the problem, if you would try to DIY this, you would be risking injury to yourself and to others and risking damage to your wiring.

Comment: I ended up having a friend who is an electrician come and get it working for me. Turned out there were 2 3-way switches causing issues along with an incorrectly wired outlet causing issues. Took a couple of hours to diagnose it but it was definitely outside of my capability.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have gotten the feeder hot mixed up and when that switch is turned off it cuts power to the other switches this is a very common diy mistake.

Ok how do you fix it? First you need a volt meter or a non contact voltage detector.

Using the meter or detector find the wire that is always hot once that is identified turn the power off at the breaker.

The always hot will need a jumper to the other switches the jumper is there it’s just the wires got mixed up so when you turned this switch off it killed the power to the other switches and receptacles. Getting the correct combination may take a couple of tries but your goal is always hot+jumper to other switches+ feed to living room/ garage these go to 1 side of the switch and the other side of the switch is the lights you want controlled by this switch.

I believe the hot was on the wrong side and it was the common hot for all the devices in the box.

So verify the hot first , then turn the power off and make connections and test. This is usually a really quick job once you understand how the wires should be connected.